# How to include two files by category id

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, include

I have one file that I want to put in this file two other files that they will be dynamic. The main file is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Gaming Ventus Let's Play - VLet's Play</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/article_style_readmore.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../styles/styles_content_static_contact/styles_alltemplate_static_contact.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/readmore_mainbody_style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../test/test2/Untitled-3.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">  
    <div id="top_header">
      <ul id="icons">
        <li><a href="http://youtube.com/" target="_blank"><img src="../../images/youtube-icon.png" alt="YT" width="32" height="32" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="../../images/facebook-icon.png" alt="Fb" width="32" height="32" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img src="../../images/twitter-icon.png" alt="Twit" width="32" height="32" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="../../images/google-icon.png" alt="Goog" width="32" height="32" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="../../images/rss-icon.png" alt="Rss" width="32" height="32" /></a></li>
      </ul>        
    </div>

    <div id="bottom_header">
      <a href="../../index.php?page=home">
        <div id="logo"><img src="../../images/Ventus_Gaming_logo.png"></div>
      </a>
      <div id="search_bar">
        <form>
          <input type="text" id="search">
          <label for="search">Search</label>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="../../index.php?page=home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="../../index.php?page=reviews">Reviews</a></li>
      <li><a href="../../index.php?page=news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="../../index.php?page=videos">Videos</a></li>
      <li><a href="../../index.php?page=photos">Photos</a></li>
      <li><a href="../../content_static_main_body/contact.php?page=contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>    

  <div id="main_body">
    <div id="main_left_nav">
  /****************************************************************\        
  <?php

    include('function_art_result_readmore.php');
    include('function_art_result_readmore_photos.php');

  ?>
  \****************************************************************/

    </div>

    <div id="right_nav">
      <div id="right_nav_about">
        About!
      </div>
      <div class="right_nav_others">
        Reviews!
      </div>
      <div class="right_nav_others">
        News!
      </div>
      <div class="right_nav_others">
        Videos!
      </div>
      <div class="right_nav_others">
        Photos!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <p>Copyright Ventus Gaming</p>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
//Ayto einai to apotelesma otan patas to read more dhladh ta post mona tous
?>
</body>
</html>
```

So in the asterisk section I have this two files that I want to include... That files have mysql code and php code. So I want to include them like something like this:

```
<?php 
  if ($CatID == 8) {
    include('function_art_result_readmore.php');       
  } else {
    include('function_art_result_readmore_photos.php');
  }
?>
```

But this is not working, is just for example. So I want to open the include file by category id so I have both files whenever I want.
Of course if there is another solution I accept it :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: From where do you get the current category ID?

Comment: I have a database and there I have the Category_ID column..if is that you are asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the category ID in the request (either GET or POST using the code below):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['category_id']) &&  $_REQUEST['category_id'] == '8') {          
  include('function_art_result_readmore.php'); 
} else {  
  include('function_art_result_readmore_photos.php'); 
}
```

`

Comment: Not working :/ it opens this file: function_art_result_readmore_photos.php in all categories.

Comment: Can you paste the request url ?

Comment: you mean this? http://localhost/Phpnbaer/admin_login_bg/includes/article_result_readmore_img.php?article_id=31

Comment: pass the category id in request param either GET/POST.. http://localhost/Phpnbaer/admin_login_bg/includes/article_result_readmore_img.php?article_id=31&category_id=8 (I Passed as GET request param in this sample link)

Comment: Sorry I was not in pc. So i try it now and it worked perfectly... Thanks a lot! Just edit your above anwer to complete it if you want :)